# how does row vectors span a row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

the column space is very easy to understand, for example, we have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0& 0 \\ 
 0&  1& 0\\
 0&  0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}
a \\  b\\ c
\end{pmatrix}$$
if we let $V_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, V_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},V_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so the product of above will be$$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1&  V_2& V_3 \end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}a \\  b\\ c\end{pmatrix}$$, so any vector in $R^3$ can be seen as $aV_1+bV_2+cV_3$

but for row space, I don't know how can I do the same thing, for example,if we set $V_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}, V_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&  1& 0 \end{pmatrix},V_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0&  0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then it becomes $$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1\\  V_2\\ V_3 \end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}a \\  b\\ c\end{pmatrix}$$, but we cannot even multiply these two matrices,can we? so how can I use row vectors to span $R^3$ in the form as $aV_1+bV_2+cV_3$ where $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are row vectors?

Another question is, are $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ the same as $\begin{pmatrix} 1&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as they all in $R_3$

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment since I don't have enough reps for that.

What about $(a\quad b\quad c)\times \begin{pmatrix} V_1\\  V_2\\ V_3 \end{pmatrix}$?

This is 1 x 3 matrix times 3 x 3 which gives you a 1 x 3 matrix.

Post multiplication of a matrix by a vector gives a linear combination of the columns of the matrix.

Pre multiplication of a matrix by a vector gives a linear combination of the rows of the matrix.

In answer to your second question:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is not the same as $\begin{pmatrix} 1&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$. A vector or point, by default (unless stated otherwise) is assumed to be a column vector. So, $\begin{pmatrix} 1&  0& 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}^t$.

The operations you can perform with a row vector are different from those that can be performed by a column vector. Examples of such different operations are exactly the two examples (pre and post multiplication) you have provided in your OP.

Comment: This is the solution. Row vectors are just transposed column vectors. So for instance, while a standard column vector equation is written $Ax=b$, taking the transpose of that gives us the form of the basic row vector equation: $xA=b$ (remember that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$). More generally, take any statement about column vectors, transpose the _whole statement_, and you got the corresponding row vector statement.